# Do I have enough data to create a salesforce php integration as a beginner?

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, soap-api, php, php-toolkit

I received a task as a part of a recruitment process although PHP and Salesforce developer experience was not specified as a requirement, but I want to try to finish it and learn something new.

> I have the following data:
>
> - Client ID
> - Client Secret
> - Athentication Target
> - Data Extension External Key

What needs to be done with it:

> Create a sample form integration that subscribes the user to a newsletter (i.e. one field) on a page written in PHP.
>
> Use the following link for reference:
>   https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/index-api.htm

I know a bit about PHP and how it connects with SQL so I will create a local version on a XAMPP server first. I've already created a developer account and downloaded the Force.com Toolkit for PHP (Version 20.0) and the [PHP API starter](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/api_starter_kits.htm) kit.

My questions are as follows:

1. Do I have all the necessary data?
2. When and where do I use the data above?
3. Does the data somehow force a specific approach (SOAP or REST)?
4. Can I somehow test if I fail/succeed? I should send the answer via e-mail.

Comment: Is this a homework or interview question by chance? It kind of reads that way.

Comment: You're right. It's a pre-interview question. I never mentioned salesforce in my resume and this task totally suprised me. Don't know if they are using this challenge to see if I'm more fit for a different position or if it's used as a tactic to discourage me. I'm not expecting a solution, just the answers to be sure if I have everything I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That will be quite easy. You actually don't even need to utilize any local DB. Assuming your PHP skills are adequate, you should have a look at the PHP SDK, which can be found on GitHub:
https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-PHP

You should especially have a look at Create Subscriber example:

```
require('ET_Client.php');
$myclient = new ET_Client();
$subscriber = new ET_Subscriber();
$subscriber->authStub = $myclient;
$subscriber->props = array("EmailAddress" => "example@example.com", "SubscriberKey" => "SDKSubscriber");
$subscriber->props['Attributes'] = array(array('Name' => 'First Name', 'Value' => 'ExactTarget Example'));
$results = $subscriber->post();
print_r($results);
```

Which can be found here:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-sdks.meta/mc-sdks/subscriber-create.htm

And yes - you have all the info you need. You will be able to use the $results to verify a succesful subscriber creation.

Good luck!

Comment: I know i'ts late to say it, but I would really like to thank you for taking the time to read and write the helpful tip - Fuel SDK was indeed the key.